# Multiple stacked footers in jQuery Mobile (put div at bottom above the nav bar)

Tags: jquery, css, mobile

I currently have a static nav bar at the bottom of my pages, and I'd like to place another div of content directly above that nav bar. Problem is that if I set it to footer, it goes in the same location as the nav bar. I thought about just absolute positioning it above the nav bar, problem is that that doesn't seem like the right answer considering when my app changes languages, the font size goes wacky (Chinese characters) and changes the size of the nav bar slightly, and it looks like crap. Not to mention that not all device resolutions are the same, etc.

Basically I've been trying to find a way to "stack" the footer divs. I want to have this div "stacked" on top of the nav bar. Is there a way to do this without ripping jqm apart?

Seems like there should be a way to set something like "footer y-index 1" or something like that to set a priority list in the way it calculates the layout.

Comment: Mike, fiddle it for a clearer understanding, jsfiddle.net?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a suggestion:

Create all variants of footer outside the page and have an empty footer tag in each page.

In pageInit:

- Select the right version of footer div that you would like to insert
- Duplicate that div by getting the html of it.
- Insert the html in the empty footer div of the page.

Comment: It's a single barebones page with jquery changing the 'pages' in the app and running functions to call. I just could not get the performance of jqm where I wanted it in regards to looking native. I just assume write the functions myself. Since the rewrite it is performing much better, not to mention it's much more flexible. I didn't think of just putting into the nav div before...it's a bit messy but it will do the job. I can just have jquery get rid of it or show it. Just drop it into the footer above the navigation. I just have to fix the css and remove all the styling on that 'upper footer'

Comment: I have exactly same experience with JQM. Looking at converting some of my code to native. At slower CPUs JQM performance is simply unacceptable. Thanks!

Comment: Just to let you know, I made my own back functionality by having the 'pages' declare their name as a variable, then when the next page is selected, it changes that to the 'back', then I have a function run on the back button selector to change it. app_nav_back = app_nav_id; app_nav_id = "thispage_whatever";  It's running much much much better now. I'm utilizing jqm for all UI elements (time saver), then my own stuff to switch in the app. Basically have it do something to all 'page' classes then load the id of the new one. Also the lack of refresh was inhibiting this project. good luck to you!